# Techniques for mitigating viewstate control tree changes on when deploying to high traffic site

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I help develop a relatively high traffic web application that uses ASP.NET WebForms. Although our use of viewstate is relatively small, we do require it currently.

When deploying a change to the main masterpage, we frequently cause currently connected users to receive an error when they next issue a POST request. The reason for this is that the viewstate tree that exists in their POST request no longer matches what the server expects to be posted. Since we are a web application, many of our pages do POST.

The full error is of course:

> Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Naturally, this is highly frustrating for our users. At the moment, we try to:

1. Minimize changes to the masterpage (at least, changes which involve server controls)
2. Deploy in low traffic periods

I have thought about doing tricks with load balancer affinity to try force newly logging in users to the newly deployed version, while keeping currently logged in users on the old version - but this seems hugely complex and maintaining multiple codebases on production isn't really where I want to go.

I appreciate the technology isn't really our friend here, but just wondered if anyone had any tips or techniques they use to mitigate this issue.

Comment: You could also minimize the viewstate, or totally remove it - especial for the controls that make the problem. I think that what you keep in viewstate, you could, ether recreate it if viewstate change, ether save it on cache, or something like that.

Comment: Why not handle the error in global.asax Application_Error and redirect the users to a page that tells them that a new version of the web page was published?

Comment: Thanks Petroj - that seems to be perhaps the best fallback option at the moment. I just wish there was a more pleasant technique somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did for something similar: I turned off Viewstate, and created a hidden field in the master page which encrypted a guid and date and time.  I used this guid and date and time to reference some values in a shared cache.

The data was small and transient and didn't need to be kept around very long.  And depending on volume and how long you can keep that cache data around, it's also possible to see how long people 'stick' to pages.

There are plenty of open source shared cache solutions that are tuned specifically for this type of role.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. We actually already use a shared cache solution to sync application state across multiple web servers. But re-engineering all existing legacy controls to point to that, instead of viewstate, would be a big task. So I guess I was looking for a get out of jail free card that doesn't exist!

Comment: To further this answer, I did this by re-engineering the base page, so that Viewstate was redirected to use this method, therefore, I only had to inherit from my base page, instead of the normal page.